# Backtesting software with custom data input

Tags: backtesting, software

I was considering to develop a custom backtesting platform for myself. However, I see that it would require some significant time and effort, and the result might not be as initially expected. So I decided to buy a professional backtesting platform. I live outside of the United States and not interested in US stocks, so my top requirement is being able to enter custom price data as input. It could be as a csv file, data source like Google or Yahoo Finance, or some other way. Also, one should be able to use 3rd party libraries in the strategy code, such that machine learning libraries or ta-lib.

Please suggest some backtesting software for these requirements. It could be both open-source and commercial.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using "Python for finance"?

There is multiple Python librarys to help you getting up to speed, e.g. take a look at [Python Algorithmic Trading Library](http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline), it's the library used in [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/) platform. It is opensource and written in python, you can use your own .csv data or built-in yahoo finance data feed. You can of course use any python library you want with it.

Answer (score 1):

Python backtesting framework [Backtesting.py](https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/) works with any kind of OHLC data and supports arbitrary indicator / machine learning library.

Answer (score 0):

[image: backtesting software]

[PyInvesting](https://pyinvesting.com) allows you to backtest your investment strategy without writing a single line of code.

- Simply fill in a form specifying your backtest details
- Create signals using both technical and fundamental data
- Backtest your prefered investment strategy (Relative Strength, Fundamentals, Moving Average and Strategic Allocation)
- Performance analysis is a breeze with our clean and beautiful user interface
- Extensive coverage of instruments (stocks, ETFs, FX and Crypto) across multiple exchanges
- Allows you to go live and profit from your investment strategy where you will receive daily email updates about any live orders.

Disclaimer: I’m the founder of [pyinvesting.com](https://pyinvesting.com), a [backtesting software](https://pyinvesting.com/blog/12/heres-why-every-investor-should-backtest-their-investment-strategy/) for stock market investors.